# Fast way to look if edge is important for graphs connectivity

Tags: c++, performance, graph, breadth-first-search, undirected-graph

I have a set of edges E, and I want to know if I can safely remove edge i in E, meaning if I remove it from the graph, the graph should still be connected.

In my understanding that implies that edge i, has to lie on a circle.
The output should be a list of indices of all edges I can't remove.

The problem:

My different solutions seem to do the right thing, but are far too slow (inefficient).

One of my solutions was:

```
1. Loop through all edges i in E
  2. Loop through all edges x in V
    3. Add edge x to the graph (excluding edge i) until nodes of i are connected or end reached
  4. If no connection possible, edge is not removable and added to the list
```

This way was way too slow.

I then decided to rewrite my code and use breadth-first-search to look if another path is possible without edge i.

I thought it would be performant enough, but it seems it's not. Either I have implemented in a very bad way or that's also the wrong algorithm for this task.

Here is the algorithm in the C++ code I have (removed some not important parts):

```
struct connection {
    int a, b;
};

void expand(int x, connection *&arr, std::set<int> &exp, int size) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (x == arr[i].a) {
            exp.insert(arr[i].b);
        }
        else if (x == arr[i].b) {
            exp.insert(arr[i].a);
        }
    }

    return;
}

// recursive breadth-first-seach

bool BFSr(std::set<int> &group, std::set<int> &visited, int goal, connection *&arr, int size) {
    if (group.empty()) return false;
    if (group.find(goal) != group.end()) return true;
    std::set<int> tempa;

    for (std::set<int>::iterator it = group.begin(); it != group.end(); ++it) {
        expand(*it, arr, tempa size);
    }

    for (std::set<int>::iterator it = visited.begin(); it != visited.end(); ++it) {
        tempa.erase(*it);
    }

    tempb = visited;
    tempb.insert(group.begin(), group.end());
    return BFSr(tempa, tempb, goal, arr, size);
}

bool BFS(int start, int goal, connection *&arr, int size) {
    std::set<int> tempa;
    std::set<int> tempb;
    tempa.insert(start);
    return BFSr(tempa, tempb, goal, arr, size);
}

int main()
{

    connection *arr = new connection[m];
    connection *con = new connection[m - 1];

    // fill arr with connections arr.a < arr.b ....

    for (int j = 0; j < (m - 1); j++) {
        con[j] = arr[j + 1];
    }

    // 1. edge for performance reasons extra
    if (!BFS(arr[0].a, arr[0].b, con, (m - 1))) {
        // connection is important therefore add to list
        printf(" %d", 1);
    }

    // Look if nodes still connected after removing connection
    for (int s = 1; s < m; s++) {

        con[s - 1] = arr[s - 1];

        if (!BFS(arr[s].a, arr[s].b, con, (m-1))) {
            // connection is important therefore add to list
            printf(" %d", s + 1);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");


    free(arr);
    free(con);

    return 0;
}
```

Do you know any solutions for me to make it faster, or do you know a better algorithm for my problem?

Comment: perhaps your BFSr function should take sets by reference, for large graphs it will definitely save you some time with copying objects

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will edit my code to use reference and then see if its much better or still has to be changed.

Comment: Seems, to not be enough unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An edge whose deletion disconnects two connected components is called a **[bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29)** and there are linear-time algorithms for finding all the bridges in a graph (usually based on depth-first search). The Wikipedia article lists one of them (due to Tarjan) as an example. [This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.0700.pdf) also gives a simple algorithm for listing all the bridges in a graph and seems to be a bit simpler than Tarjan's algorithm.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version of your algorithm (I guess you will get industry standard optimization implementation of graph and various algorithm for free):

I am referring to this image as graph model.
Gist (from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105367/finding-bridges-in-a-graph-c-boost))

1. find articulation points
2. all points with single out-edge are
   articulation points (boost graph won't return these)- these edges
   are automatically bridging edges
3. for each articulation point-
   loop over each outedge, if outedge already not bridging edge- then
   remove the edge and check for graph components and add the edge back
   again

At the end it will print ***Edge(a,g) connects components in graph***

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/biconnected_components.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>

#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>

typedef boost::adjacency_list <boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS> Graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor edge_t;

//  reference:
//  http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2005/08/13098.php
//
struct edge_t_hasher
{
    std::size_t operator()(const edge_t& e) const
    {
        auto prop = e.get_property();
        std::hash<decltype(prop)> hasher;
        return hasher(prop);
    }
};

typedef std::unordered_set<edge_t, edge_t_hasher> UnorderedBoostEdgeSet;

Graph getGraph()
{
    Graph g;

    vertex_t aVtx = boost::add_vertex(g);
    vertex_t bVtx = boost::add_vertex(g);
    vertex_t cVtx = boost::add_vertex(g);
    vertex_t dVtx = boost::add_vertex(g);
    vertex_t eVtx = boost::add_vertex(g);
    vertex_t fVtx = boost::add_vertex(g);
    vertex_t gVtx = boost::add_vertex(g);
    vertex_t hVtx = boost::add_vertex(g);
    vertex_t iVtx = boost::add_vertex(g);

    boost::add_edge(dVtx, cVtx, g);
    boost::add_edge(dVtx, bVtx, g);
    boost::add_edge(cVtx, bVtx, g);
    boost::add_edge(aVtx, bVtx, g);
    boost::add_edge(bVtx, eVtx, g);
    boost::add_edge(eVtx, fVtx, g);
    boost::add_edge(aVtx, fVtx, g);
    boost::add_edge(aVtx, gVtx, g);// edge connecting components
    boost::add_edge(gVtx, iVtx, g);
    boost::add_edge(gVtx, hVtx, g);
    boost::add_edge(hVtx, iVtx, g);

    return g;
}

UnorderedBoostEdgeSet bridgingEdgesForGraph(const Graph& graph)
{
    UnorderedBoostEdgeSet bridgeEdges;

    std::unordered_set<vertex_t> articulationVertices;
    boost::articulation_points(graph, std::inserter(articulationVertices, articulationVertices.end()));

    //  add all the single connected vertices to the articulation vertices
    auto vtxIters = boost::vertices(graph);
    for (auto it = vtxIters.first, end = vtxIters.second; it != end; ++it)
    {
        if (boost::out_degree(*it, graph) == 1)
            bridgeEdges.insert(*(boost::out_edges(*it, graph).first));
    }

    std::vector<vertex_t> componentsInGraph(boost::num_vertices(graph));
    int numComponentsInGraph = boost::connected_components(graph, &componentsInGraph[0]);

    //  for each articulation vertex now get edges and check if removing that
    //  edge causes graph change in connected components
    //

    //  copy the graph- so we can iterate over the outeges of vertices
    //  we will be fiddling with the copy- since the vtx descriptors are
    //  ints- they stay same across copy and removing edge operation
    auto graph2 = graph;
    for (auto vtx : articulationVertices)
    {
        auto outEdges = boost::out_edges(vtx, graph);
        for (auto it = outEdges.first, end = outEdges.second; it != end; ++it)
        {
            auto edge = *it;
            if (bridgeEdges.find(edge) != bridgeEdges.end())
                continue;

            //  map this edge to graph2 edge- for removal and eventual addition
            auto src = boost::source(edge, graph);
            auto tgt = boost::target(edge, graph);

            auto edge2 = boost::edge(src, tgt, graph2).first;

            boost::remove_edge(edge2, graph2);
            std::vector<vertex_t> componentsInGraph2(boost::num_vertices(graph2));
            int numComponentsInGraph2 = boost::connected_components(graph2, &componentsInGraph2[0]);

            // bridging edge- graph #components changed
            if (numComponentsInGraph != numComponentsInGraph2)
                bridgeEdges.insert(edge);

            //  add the edge back to graph2
            boost::add_edge(src, tgt, graph2);
        }
    }

    return bridgeEdges;
}

int main()
{
    const Graph& graph = getGraph();
    const auto& bridgingEdges = bridgingEdgesForGraph(graph);

    const char* array = {"ABCDEFGHI"};
    for (auto edge : bridgingEdges)
    {
        std::cout << "Edge(" << array[boost::source(edge, graph)] << ", " << array[boost::target(edge, graph)] 
                  << ") is a bridging edge" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hm. It seems to determine the nodes/vertices that are important to the graph and not the edges/connections.

In the example Graph the edge ( A <-> G) would be the answer, or better the indice for it.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found out how those special edges are called: Bridges.

And therefore I found a site giving an DFS algorithm for finding all bridges.

It's fast enough for my purposes.

[DFS algorithm for finding Bridges in a undirected Graph](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bridge-in-a-graph/)

Thank you Sarang, your post made me find the correct search words for the site.